# Evento click en listview o gridview

Tags: android, gridview

Tengo un gridview con imagen y texto y necesito controlar el evento click y saber cuando se pulsa sobre la imagen o sobre el texto en una determinada fila. He probado con el parametro id de setOnItemClickListener pero no veo forma de solucionarlo. ¿ Hay alguna forma de saber en que objeto se ha activado el evento click ?

---

Reformulo la pregunta:

Tengo un listview definido

listview.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="#4892d2" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPedido"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#4892d2"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingLeft="0sp"
        android:paddingTop="0sp"
        android:paddingRight="0sp"
        android:paddingBottom="0sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="Pedido"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

En el evento del listview setOnItemClickListener necesito abrir una activity si pulsan sobre el TextView txtPedido o realizar otra accion si se pulsa sobre la imagen

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView p = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textPedido);

            Intent i = new Intent(PedidosPendientes.this, LineasActivity.class);
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putLong("pedido", Long.parseLong(p.getText().toString()));
            i.putExtras(extras);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hola, puedes hacer el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código (en texto, no imagen) que has utilizado.

Comment: Para poder tener una idea mas clara de tu caso podrias compartir el codigo que has hecho. Como creaste esa vista gridview? Utilizaste un RecyclerView y su adaptador o simplemente estan quemados en la vista?

Answer (score 0):

Debes obtener la referencia de las vistas `txtPedido` e `img1` , después define un `onclicklistener` que dentro realizara un intent:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        //Obtiene referencia de TextView txtPedido
        TextView tvPedido = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textPedido);
        //Define onclicklistener para txtPedido
        tvPedido.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

          Intent i = new Intent(PedidosPendientes.this, LineasActivity.class);
          Bundle extras = new Bundle();
              extras.putLong("pedido", Long.parseLong(tvPedido.getText().toString()));
              i.putExtras(extras);
              startActivity(i);

                }
            });

        //Obtiene referencia de ImageView
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img1);
        //Define onclicklistener para ImageView
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

          Intent i = new Intent(PedidosPendientes.this, LineasActivity.class);
          Bundle extras = new Bundle();              
              i.putExtras(extras);
              startActivity(i);

                }
            });
            
        }
    });
```